# Conditional display of value depending on previous value in ng-repeat - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

The following code will display:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in userscheds">{{x.week_day}} {{x.time_start}}-{{x.time_end}}
```

.

```
Monday 08:00-12:00 
Monday 13:00-17:00 
Tuesday 08:00-12:00 
Tuesday 13:00-17:00 
Wednesday 08:00-12:00 
Wednesday 13:00-17:00 
Thursday 08:00-12:00 
Thursday 13:00-17:00 
Friday 08:00-12:00 
Friday 13:00-17:00
```

Would it be possible to display week_day only once by comparing the previous week_day value? Like this:

```
Monday 08:00-12:00 
       13:00-17:00 
Tuesday 08:00-12:00 
        13:00-17:00 
Wednesday 08:00-12:00 
          13:00-17:00 
Thursday 08:00-12:00 
         13:00-17:00 
Friday 08:00-12:00 
       13:00-17:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write somethink like :

```
{{ $index > 0 && x.week_day != userscheds[$index-1].week_day ? x.week_day : ''}} {{x.time_start}}-{{x.time_end}}
```

Ooops *Edit :

```
{{ $index == 0 || x.week_day != userscheds[$index-1].week_day ? x.week_day : ''}} {{x.time_start}}-{{x.time_end}}
```

Comment: btw as @petraveryanov said, you'll better customize your model to avoid that usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can put {{getWeeks($index)}}, in function you can do whatever - like check previous indices and display value if it differs.

It is bad way thow. Better first change you data structure in controller.